Parsing nested map/struct yaml in golang
I'm a bit of a newbie in golang, and have gotten stuck on a specific yaml-parsing issue and all my googling indicates that this should work, hence I'm doing something stupid that makes it nofunctional.
Given this yaml:
table1:
  Columns:
    col1: mycol
    col2: mycol2
  Where: a = 1

I try to do this:
package main

import "fmt"
import "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"

type TableSpec struct {
    Columns map[string]string
    Where string
}

var (
    transforms map[string]TableSpec
)

func main() {
    var (
        t map[string]TableSpec
    )
    
    yamlFile := []byte(`table1:
  Columns:
    col1: mycol
    col2: mycol2
  Where: a = 1`)
      
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(yamlFile, &t)
    
    if (err != nil) {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s", t["table1"].Columns)
}

I'm expecting this to output the col1, col2 keys in the map, but I just get an empty map.  Am I misunderstanding golang typing and structs?

https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v3#Unmarshal

Struct fields are only unmarshalled if they are exported (have an upper case first letter), and are unmarshalled using the field name lowercased as the default key. Custom keys may be defined via the "yaml" name in the field tag: the content preceding the first comma is used as the key, and the following comma-separated options are used to tweak the marshalling process (see Marshal). Conflicting names result in a runtime error.


Either specify the upper case keys in the yaml:"..." struct tags.
Or convert your yaml file to use lowercase keys.

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/udh4fxSJHsM

Hm, so you are saying, I need to have upper case in the struct, but lower case in the yaml? That seems to work, but feels really counter intuitive

@jishi you can have uppercase in both the struct fields and the yaml keys, but then you must also provide struct tags that contain the uppercase yaml keys.
